# Truncate all tables in a Snoflake schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any simple command to truncate all tables inside a snowflake schema ?

From what I've seen, the [truncate table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/truncate-table.html#truncate-table) command only works on a single table

Answer (score 3):

There is not such a command as far as I know, but you may use a simple query to generate the required truncate commands, and then run them:

```
select 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || TABLE_CATALOG || '.' || TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || table_name || ';' cmd 
from information_schema.tables 
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'GOKHAN_DB' and TABLE_SCHEMA='PUBLIC';
```

Of course, you can also create a stored procedure (with JS) for this purpose.

Comment: "...you can also create a stored procedure (with JS) for this purpose" -- Already done, for any generated SQL on Snowflake: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Executing-Multiple-SQL-Statements-in-a-Stored-Procedure

Comment: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html) contains also rows for views. I suggest adding  `AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` to avoid trying to truncate views(it will produce an error).